# Adding hotkey functionality to a Silverlight button, but underscore character does not work

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm currently designing my Silverlight Application interface in Expression Blend 4.  I'd like the user to be able to press the Alt key and see underlined characters on buttons to provide hotkey functionality.  This used to be done in VB by adding an "&" character before the letter you wanted underlined (eg. "&Save").  In XAML, my understanding is that you do it with an underscore ("_").  However, when I use the underscore, the underscore character is literally appearing in my button's content.  ("_Save" shows up on the button).  What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the button's XAML:
`<Button Content="_Save" Height="30" Foreground="DarkGray"/>`

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm too new to this and just am not finding existing help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this do it for you?

```
  <Button x:Name="Play" Margin="1,2"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="shortcut key: P" 
    AutomationProperties.AccessKey="P">
    <TextBlock><Underline>P</Underline>lay</TextBlock>
  </Button>
```

[Keyboard support](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/localization-and-accessibility/making-silverlight-applications-accessible#KeyboardSupport)

Comment: This does appear to work, thank you.  However, any reason why simply adding the underscore does not?  I'm simply curious, since all other information I've read indicates that's how  you do it.  Seems like a lot of unnecessary coding to get something to work that is supposed to be built right in.  Thanks again for the code!

Comment: It might have been "the old way" to do it.  I personally do not have experience with silverlight.  The link in the bottom of the answer should be helpful.  Also, I guess xaml != vb style.  The site has examples on how to do it in xaml, vb and c#

Comment: @QuittersNL It seems the underscore shortcut convention works in WPF, but not in Silverlight.

Comment: @McGarnagle. I have the same issue. I have a button `Home`. The char `H` is underscored. But Alt H goes to Help in internet explorer menu.